# How to get values from nested json in java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am creating a project using spring boot 2.0.3 in which I have to parse json and get values by using its keys. My problem is that I have a key which is present at multiple levels in the json and I want to get value of all its occurrences. For example below is the object that I'm using :-

```
{
  "test": {
    id:1,
    name:"test1",
    class:"test2"
  },
  "boolean": true,
  "color": "#82b92c",
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object_": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f",
    "test": {
       id:2,
       name:"test1",
       class:"test2"
    }
  },
  "object": {
    "object": {
       "test": {
          id:3,
          name:"test1",
          class:"test2"
        }
    },
    "test": {
        id:4,
        name:"test1",
        class:"test2"
    }
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

There are four occurrences of key **test** now I want to get all the values of it.
Please suggest how can I get it's values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java DTO classes as controller method parameters (so that Spring Boot automatically does conversion), you will have nested DTOs for nested JSON objects.

Something like this in your case:

```
public class TestDto { 
    int id;
    String name;
    String clazz; //can't use class as it is reserved keyword
}

public class Body {
    TestDto test;
}
```

BTW, I don't think that several `test` keys is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below recursion logic will help to parse Json.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JacksonJsonParser parser= (JacksonJsonParser) JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
    Map jsonMap=parser.parseMap("{\"test\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test1\",\"class\":\"test2\"},\"boolean\":true,\"color\":\"#82b92c\",\"null\":null,\"number\":123,\"object_\":{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":\"f\",\"test\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"test1\",\"class\":\"test2\"}},\"object\":{\"object\":{\"test\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"test1\",\"class\":\"test2\"}},\"test\":{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"test1\",\"class\":\"test2\"}},\"string\":\"Hello World\"}");
    getTestDetails(jsonMap);
}

private static void getTestDetails(Map jsonMap) {
    for(Object key:jsonMap.keySet()){

        if("test".equals(key.toString())){
            System.out.println(jsonMap.get(key));
        }else{

            if(jsonMap.get(key) instanceof Map){
                getTestDetails((Map)jsonMap.get(key));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use org json library to read the JSON from a String.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107

Once you have the jar in place.

Below code should print all the jsons with key "test"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = "{\"test\": {\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test1\",\"class\":\"test2\"},\"boolean\": true,\"color\": \"#82b92c\",\"null\": null,\"number\": 123,\"object_\": {\"a\": \"b\",\"c\": \"d\",\"e\": \"f\",   \"test\": {   \"id\":2,    \"name\":\"test1\",    \"class\":\"test2\"  }  },  \"object\": {    \"object\": {       \"test\": {    \"id\":3,    \"name\":\"test1\",    \"class\":\"test2\"  }    },    \"test\": {    \"id\":4,    \"name\":\"test1\",    \"class\":\"test2\"  }  },  \"string\": \"Hello World\"}";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    System.out.println(json);
    Iterator keys = json.keys();
    getTestKeyObj(json);
}

public static void getTestKeyObj(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    Iterator keys = jsonObj.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
            System.out.println("Test JSON: "+jsonObj.get(key));
        }else {
            if ( jsonObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
                getTestKeyObj((JSONObject) jsonObj.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```